# Is there a way for me to set the class of an object using the ? notation in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
data-ng-class="{trueStatus: stat.correct == true; }"
```

But I would like to have the class be set to trueStatue if stat.correct == true and undefStatus if stat.correct is not true.

Is there a shorthand way that I can do this with Angular or do I need to have two different checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data-ng-class="{true: 'trueStatus', false: 'undefStatus'}[stat.correct == true]"
```

If you have more conditions:

```
data-ng-class="{'class1': someValue == 1, 'class2': someValue == 2, 
'class3': someValue == 3"
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this soon. It looks like a very clean solution. Is this something documented that I missed or just something that you found yourself. Can it be extended to more than two conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
data-ng-class="(stat.correct == true) && 'trueStatus' || (stat.correct != true) && 'undefStatus'"
```